# Bluetooth can't connect any more if my application crashed

Tags: android, bluetooth, reconnect

I developed an application which use Bluetooth to connect to another device(called B). But I found one issue is that when my application crashed on Android tablet, it can not connect to B any more unless I restart the Android tablet.
My Android tablet is ASUS MEMO Pad HD7. If I use sony ericsson phone or SAMSUNG Note, this issue will not happen.
Does any one have any idea for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the device is still connected. You probably don't need to reboot the tablet; just turn Bluetooth off and then back on again.

Comment: If my application crashed on the other tablet, system will disconnect automatically and ASUS doesn't. If I turned off Bluetooth on device or  on tablet and turn on later, the issue still exists unless I reboot the tablet. I searched all function of Bluetooth on Android reference, I can't find any function to reset Bluetooth. Could your provide any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It might issue of Visibility of bluetooth . bcoz is is visible for only some perticular time only.